# TypeError: 'BertTokenizer' object is not callable "bert-base-multilingual-cased"

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

From Jupyter notebook and using this package versions:
Name: transformers Version: 2.1.1
torch:'2.0.1'
Name: tensorflow Version: 2.13.0

I am running this code:

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModel
import torch

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-multilingual-cased")
model = AutoModel.from_pretrained("bert-base-multilingual-cased")

text = 'welcome to Miami'
inputs = tokenizer(text, return_tensors='pt', padding=True)
with torch.no_grad():
    outputs = model(**inputs)
    embeddings = outputs.last_hidden_state[:, 0, :]
embeddings.detach().cpu().numpy()
```

And I am gettning this error:

TypeError: 'BertTokenizer' object is not callable

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the issue is because of the old transformers package version (https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/5580#issuecomment-655001985)

Maybe, try upgrading to a newer version of the transformers package or use `tokenizer.tokenize()` to tokenize your text.